# Signature verification for Repository hardware failed and Update Error Repository unknown [OpenSuse Leap 15_2]

Tags: linux, repository, opensuse, zypper, software-update

System updates app gives an error while checking updates.

If it checks as routine gives a notification "Signature verification for Repository hardware failed".

Second error occurs when I want to check updates by using Software Updates app and ist says "Update Error, Repository unknown".

I tried `zypper clean` and `zypper ref` got no error everything seems fine. What to do?

[Update Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqMT8.png)

[Got more detailed error here after posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6tWQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
# rm -rf  /var/cache/zypp
# zypper up
```

or try a mirror:

https://mirrors.opensuse.org/

download.opensuse.org is a redirector, so maybe a mirror helps.